# Error al crear más de 15 hojas dompdf

Tags: php, html, dompdf

Estoy generando cotizaciones pdf de productos y todo bien con esta librería DOMPDF, pero al generar una cotización con más de 45 productos, me sale "fatal error maximum execution time of 45 seconds exceeded" lo solucione poniendo esto ini_set('max_execution_time', 200), pero de igual manera no me genera el pdf y se queda cargando y no hace nada.

Estuve buscando en la documentación de la librería pero hasta el momento no he encontrado algo que me ayude a solucionarlo.

Espero que me puedan ayudar,saludos.

Comment: Puede que el problema sea a otro nivel: por ejemplo que la base de datos o la consulta  no está optimizada,  eso hace que tarde mucho y dé ese error. Si es el caso deberías revisar, por ejemplo ejecutando la consulta aparte y viendo si tarda demasiado.

Comment: De hecho lo que hago es generar un HTML el cual se aloja en el servidor, y después pongo las opciones de generar ese html a pdf o generarlo y enviarlo por correo, (al generar el HTML lo hace bien), el detalle es cuando envio ese html creado, al codigo para generar el pdf es cuando deja de funcionar, como comento deja de funcionar cuando las cotizaciones alcanza mas de 12 hojas, porque cotizaciones menores a esa cantidad de hojas, funciona de maravilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer ya logre solucionarlo, y era porque en las descripciones de los equipos de la cotización tenia caracteres especiales, se los quite y funciono. Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema puedan checarlo, pensé que era por la cantidad de paginas, pero no era por que 2 o tres equipos tenían caracteres especiales en sus descripciones[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar poniendo los límites de memoria al máximo para ver si se soluciona tu error.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Si tu documento se genera, vas configurando estos parámetros según tu necesidad.

Comment: Intente de la manera que me comentaste, pero aun sigue sin funcionar, ahora al pasar de un rato ya me marca "504 Gateway Time-out", la verdad no entiendo porque con más de 10 hojas ya no genera el pdf

Comment: Intenta pasando el `set_time_limit(500);`

Comment: Por ahí leí que si usas tablas anidadas o si tu contenido se desborda también te genera ese error

Comment: Pues si debe ser eso de las tablas anidadas, por que si genero una que otra, pero, tu de casualidad sabes de alguna otra librería o código para convertir el html en pdf? Por que al parecer con esta librería no voy a lograrlo.

Comment: Otras alternativas sugeridas en esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888268/dompdf-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded) son [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/) o [wkhtmltopdf.org](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/). Personalmente no las he usado, pero seguro han de servirte ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias, las analizaré

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo error pero lo soluciones haciendo uso de utf8_decode('texto con carácter especial') a todos los textos que tenían caracteres especiales.